# Getting the runs offline tag

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've notice that the chrome store now features some apps with a "runs offline" badge and has a new category for this kind of applications, the app I developed works offline perfectly fine but in the store it isn't displayed as such, is there something I need to add to the manifest or did I missed something in my code to indicate that it can run offline?

Comment: How are we supposed to know if you forgot something in the manifest, if we don't get to take a look at it ? Have you set the **[`offline_enabled` property](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/offline_enabled.html)** ?

Comment: I asked if something needs to be added to the manifest, not if i missed something in it, i'll check the property, thanks

Comment: In order to know if you need to add something, don't wee need to know what is already there ? There is no sense in telling you to set the `offline_enabled` property to true, if you have already done that and the problem still persists. There is this **[great post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)** you might want to take a look at.

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot, post it as answer so i can mark is as solved

Comment: Roberto, in case you're not understanding what ExpertSystem is saying, PLEASE EDIT YOUR QUESTION to include your manifest. Your question is incomplete even though ExpertSystem was able to guess the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the **[`offline_enabled` property](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/offline_enabled.html)** to **true** in the manifest.